# How to change KMail composer default settings?

Tags: kde, opensuse, settings, fontconfig, kmail

I use KMail on OpenSuse. How can I store default settings for font, font size, font color, background color and so on in such a way that I get them every time that I open the program?

Please consider this fact that I don't have root access in my machine and using another product is not an option here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a [link given on gmane site](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.kde.devel.kmail/44153):

> It would be nice to be able to click "Load Profile", select "Purist" (loading the fonts from the KDE global
>   settings), then have an option to update the current custom settings to match that profile, and then
>   **tweak** those settings for KMail by checking the "Use custom fonts" check box.

Comment: The link helped to set the default font and font size, but it seems that KMail's composer does not support a human understandable approach to customization.

Answer (score 0):

Click "Configure KMail", and then choose the Appearance category.  Make sure you are on the "Fonts" tab.

Ensure "Use custom fonts" is ticked.  Then, from the "Apply to" drop down menu, select "Composer".  Then you can pick your font and click [OK].

Comment: Thanks to Thanks to "bastl" and "xmanmonk" on LinuxQuestions.org for the info: [KMail > Compose, how to set default HTML font size?](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/kmail-compose-how-to-set-default-html-font-size-875682/). (And "lefty.crupps" for the question.)